# Exception thrown: 'System.ApplicationException' in renderdocui.exe

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, networking, timeout

I have been stuck in step 9 of the "Setup for Capturing" of the following tutorial 
https://bitbucket.org/visinf/projects-2016-playing-for-data

I am debugging renderdocui.exe and then click on the capture and here's the errors I receive. Any insight?

```
'renderdocui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'renderdocui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\mona\playing-for-data\renderdoc\x64\Debug\renderdocui.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'renderdocui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: renderdocui.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'renderdocui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: renderdocui.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'renderdocui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: renderdocui.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'renderdocui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: renderdocui.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'renderdocui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: renderdocui.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'renderdocui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: renderdocui.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
'renderdocui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: renderdocui.exe): Loaded 'Microsoft.GeneratedCode'. 
'renderdocui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: renderdocui.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\mona\playing-for-data\renderdoc\x64\Debug\WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x6a8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.ApplicationException' in renderdocui.exe
Exception thrown: 'System.ApplicationException' in renderdocui.exe
The thread 0x176c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

also
[image]

Also here's the log I get from renderdocui:

```
RENDERDOC:  [15:49:29]             core.cpp( 242) - Log     - RenderDoc v0.27 x64 (NO_GIT_COMMIT_HASH_DEFINED) loaded in replay application
RENDERDOC:  [15:50:55]    win32_process.cpp( 307) - Log     - Injecting renderdoc into process 7732
RENDERDOC:  [15:50:55]    win32_process.cpp( 180) - Debug   - Injecting call to RENDERDOC_SetLogFile
RENDERDOC:  [15:50:55]    win32_process.cpp( 180) - Debug   - Injecting call to RENDERDOC_SetCaptureOptions
RENDERDOC:  [15:50:55]    win32_process.cpp( 180) - Debug   - Injecting call to RENDERDOC_GetRemoteAccessIdent
RENDERDOC:  [15:50:55]    win32_network.cpp( 323) - Debug   - connect before timeout
RENDERDOC:  [15:50:55]    remote_access.cpp( 389) - Log     - Got remote handshake: PlayGTAV () [7732]
RENDERDOC:  [15:50:56]    win32_network.cpp( 169) - Warning - recv: 10054
RENDERDOC:  [15:50:59]    win32_network.cpp( 317) - Debug   - connect timed out
RENDERDOC:  [15:50:59]    win32_network.cpp( 344) - Warning - Failed to connect to localhost:38920
RENDERDOC:  [15:51:02]    win32_network.cpp( 317) - Debug   - connect timed out
RENDERDOC:  [15:51:02]    win32_network.cpp( 344) - Warning - Failed to connect to localhost:38920
```

I am not sure what my approach should be for debugging this problem and fixing it. With both Capture (say with enabling hooking for children) or Global Process Hook, no overlay is shown in GTA5 game.

In step 9, it is mentioned to make sure that system paths points to OpenEXR libs and you can see them here:
[image]

Also when I click on the global process hook and then start the game, I get the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my game is not from `Steam` but from `Rockstar games`. Apparently that's why I don't need `global process hook` and `capture` works. However, I built everything from scratch (a fresh start by downloading the git repo), and used `release` and `x64` configurations instead of `debug` and `x64` configuration. Now when I select `hook into children` options and select `GTAVLauncher.exe` for executable and click on capture, it shows the `overlay` in the upper left corner and with pressing `F12` or `Print Screen` however after every capture is saved, I have to press F12 again which makes it rather hard as I also have to play the game at the same time with a wireless controller. I wonder if someone could share their experience wrt with me. 
Also I added this to my global system paths in edit environmental variables section:

```
C:\Program Files\ilmbase\include\OpenEXR
```

and then restarted the system. 
Note that if you are using `script hook v` or `script hook v.NET` `dll` in the game folder, the capturing/game will crash and if you debug the game it will tell that `script hook v is violating access`.